# How to test random events in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've encountered an interesting task.

Need to make a method that would randomly (in 10-15% cases) modify a string in a certain way.

How do I do that with TDD?

E.g. how to make sure that probability of modification will be not more than 15%?

Thx.

Comment: generate a random number in between (and including) 1 and 100 and only modify the string if the number is <= 15.

Comment: It's going to be random, so it's difficult to *make sure* that it's not more than 15%. Of course it also depends how often you run your task. The more you run it the closer to 15% it will be. As for testing: you can run the task many times and make sure the percentage is in a certain range. If you want it to be between 10% and 15%, obviously you would have to use `rand <= 0.125`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use random number generation:

```
def change_string_fifteen_percent_of_the_time
    if rand() <= 0.15
        # change string here
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to test: Run your method 100 times (for example) and assert that the string didn't change more than 15 times.

Comment: @Mischa If it fails, the requirements of the method are not met.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The method should be changed (to `rand <= 0.125` or something), not the test.